# Can I use MOTOR for mongoengine?

Tags: pymongo, mongoengine

I want to know, is there a possible way to use Motor with mongoengine(not motorengine because this library is not supported)? If not, is there another way to use Models for pyMongo like in mongoengine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MongoEngine strictly support `pymongo` as driver as explained [here](https://docs.mongoengine.org/faq.html#does-mongoengine-support-asynchronous-drivers-motor-txmongo)